# Letting visitors try out user-only features that write to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, registration, user-management

My site lets people create database entries (which most rails apps do), and I realized that there's a huge drop-off from landing on the site to actually signing up to try it. Basically the service lets users build their own document by combining different components. I'm thinking about adding an interface where visitors who are not yet registered can try out the features (building stuff) and ask them to sign up at the last stage, when they're about to publish their document.

First thing that comes to mind is use HTML5 local storage, but then another idea came to mind: maybe I could create a temporary user whenever a visitor tries out the features, and then later remove them from the database if they don't sign in. I'm not sure if this is safe, but this seems like it might be easier than dealing with all the local storage issues.

What would be the best practice for this type of situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 storage would be an option, tho most likely a lot of client side coding.

Other options would be to have a duplicate table of these 'demo' documents which you can clear every now and again for users that did not sign up.  You could also just store the document in the user session, as you don't need it permanently stored, and then store it in the database once they have signed up.

Comment: I ended up using persist.js to store everything locally and then storing them right after sign up.